# r studio directs me to the wrong url when trying to use install.packges()

Tags: r, package

I get the following error:

> Warning in install.packages :
>     unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.3:
>     cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES'

Does anyone know how i can change the default download link?

Comment: That's just a warning. Does it actually cause a problem for you? Is there an actual error somewhere? You can try choosing a different mirror with `chooseCRANmirror()`.

Comment: @MrFlick yes i can't download the package and i am using the global cran

Comment: So what’s the actual command you are running and what’s the actual error (not warning) you are getting?

Comment: You most likely have an overly-sensitive firewall / antivirus in place. Temporarily disabling that may solve the issue. First hand experience (I teach R) and seen that a lot!

Comment: @MrFlick install.package("ggplot2")   cannot open URL 'cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'; it keeps directing to the "/packages" which is actually just text

Comment: I assume you mean `install.packages()`, not `install.package`. How that function works is it contacts the repository mirror and asks for a list of all the packages it knows with the file path to the actual package bundle and current version and requirements and such. Can you access other URLs from this computer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below method.

`install.packages('Package_name', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`

Comment: cannot open URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'                    it keeps directing to the "/packages" which is actually just text

Comment: i think you might facing problem due to firewall restrictions. or are you selecting Install from repository(CRAN) . you might be selecting install from packages archieve